# Why does my form option dropdown not retain the query param? It works elsewhere in my application

Tags: python, html, forms, jinja2

I am using python FastAPI and Jinja2 and my selected_watchlist_id is printing correctly.

This is when I load the page:
[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmx4K.png)

and then after clicking submit button it just resets my selection:
[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPPuE.png)

```
@app.get("/") #function for the root page
def stocks(request: Request):
    html = "page_stocks.html"
    data = run_sql("""
        SELECT s.id, symbol, name, exchange, shortable, close FROM stock s
        JOIN stock_price_daily spd
        ON s.id = spd.stock_id
        AND spd.date = (select max(date) as date from stock_price_daily)
        ORDER BY exchange desc, symbol
    """)
    headings = ['','ID', 'Symbol', 'Name', 'Exchange', 'Shortable', 'Last Close', 'Add to Watchlist']

    watchlists = run_sql("""
        SELECT * FROM watchlist
    """)
    selected_watchlist_id = None
    selected_watchlist_id = request.query_params.get('selected_watchlist', None)
    print(selected_watchlist_id)

    return templates.TemplateResponse(html, 
    {'request': request,
     'headings': headings, 
     'data':data, 
     'watchlists':watchlists,
     'selected_watchlist':selected_watchlist_id}
     )
```

```html
    <form>
        <select method='get' name='selected_watchlist'>
            {% for watchlist in watchlists %}
                <option value='{{watchlist.id}}' {% if watchlist.id == selected_watchlist %}selected='selected' {% endif %}> {{watchlist.name}}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
        <input type='submit' value='Select watchlist to add to'>
    </form>
```

Comment: I don't think the `select` element has a `method` attribute. That might be a reason for confusion. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

Comment: It does, it’s just usually set by default unless you specify POST method

Comment: The `form` element has a `method` attribute, not `select`. You should introduce a test to check whether the request is `post` or `get` I believe.